# Connecting database to GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, dao

I'm running into some difficulties with getting my code to work properly with a GUI. I've created a simple login program connected to a database, which in the GUI lets the user type in a username and password, which is then prompted to the database in order to see if the username and password exists. I've created a class that connects to the database, and one DAO-class, that executes the SQL-statements. I've also got two more classes where one of them is an interface and one contains unimplemented methods for later on.

Now, what I'm having problems with is connecting the GUI to my database, which should be done via the DAO-class. My GUI has two textfields which should be used to compare the usernames and passwords to each other, but i don't know how to do it. Also, my DAO-class is not exactly implemented for it, since it take an int as a parameter.

If you could help me out I'd be greatful.

UserDAO-class:

```
public class UserDAO implements IDao<User> {

    DemoDB DemoDBSingleton = null;

    public UserDAO() {
        DemoDBSingleton = DemoDB.getInstance();
    }

    @Override

    public User get(int id) throws NoSuchElementException {
        User user = null;
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = DemoDBSingleton
                    .excecuteQuery("SELECT user_name, password FROM users WHERE id=" + id);
            if (!resultSet.next())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("The user " + id + " doesn't exist in database");
            else
                DemoDBSingleton.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

GUI-class:

```
import dao.UserDAO;

public class LoginGUI {
    DemoDB DemoDBSingleton = null;
    ResultSet rs;

    UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();
    JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame("Welcome to your app");
    JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Användarnamn:");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Lösenord:");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton b = new JButton("Login");

    public LoginGUI() {
        DemoDBSingleton = DemoDB.getInstance();
        frame();

    }

    private void frame() {
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        loginFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loginFrame.setVisible(false);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(null);
        l.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 21));
        l.setBounds(102, 173, 169, 41);
        p.add(l);
        t.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        t.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        t.setBounds(303, 177, 169, 41);
        p.add(t);
        l1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 21));
        l1.setBounds(102, 290, 93, 26);
        p.add(l1);
        t1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        t1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        t1.setBounds(303, 287, 169, 41);
        p.add(t1);
        b.setBounds(334, 375, 110, 52);
        p.add(b);

        f.getContentPane().add(p);


    }


    private class ClickListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();





        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoginGUI();

    }

}
```

Comment: Your DAO class is clearly wrong - you want to input the user and password and output the ID, not the other way around. And you need to use it in the listener of the submit button of your login form.

Comment: Yes, as I stated it is indeed wrong. But I need help to modify it so that I can input the username and password like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you do it this way

```
public class UserDAO implements IDao<User> {

    DemoDB DemoDBSingleton = null;

    public UserDAO() {
        DemoDBSingleton = DemoDB.getInstance();
    }

    @Override

    public boolean login(String userName, String password) throws NoSuchElementException {
        boolean login = false;
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = DemoDBSingleton
                    .excecuteQuery("SELECT user_name, password FROM users WHERE user_name='" + userName + "' AND password = '" + password + "'");
            if (resultSet.next())
                login = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DemoDBSingleton.close();
        return login;
    }
}
```

and correct your text fields

```
JTextField txtUserName = new JTextField(10);
JPasswordField txtPassword = new JPasswordField(10);
```

and the click event

```
private class ClickListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();

        if (userDao.login(txtUserName.getText(), txtPassword.getText())) {
            // here you redirect to your main window
        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect user or password!!!");
    }

}
```

Comment: @Isreal-ICM I will try it out when I get back home and answer here how it turned out. Thank you so much for your input!